# Why when a variable is used within another variable, its value its fixed to first declaration?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I would expect the output to be "text something different" but instead it is "text something".

```
var dynamic = "something";

var thistext = "text " + dynamic;

dynamic = "something different";

console.log(thistext);
```

Changing the variable "dynamic" after declaring the variable "thistext", which contains it, does not change the value of "dynamic" within the  "thistext".

I am sure this is something basic, but I think I do not know this rule or the best way to avoid this situation.

A Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5wwpvgt/

Comment: `thistext` is only evaluated once, changes on `dynamic` won't update it.

Comment: For your desired result, you can add that line of code inside a method and simply call it keeping dynamic variable available within the scope of that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when a variable is used within another variable, its value is fixed to first declaration?

You are not "using a variable within another variable". You are **using a variable in an expression**, the evaluated result of which happens to be being assigned to another variable. Expressions are evaluated **when they are encountered**, with the **current** values of any variables within them. There's no particular word for this behavior, since it is so fundamental to JS (and all other imperative/procedural languages).

Expressions are not dynamic definitions of calculations which are magically kept updated when their inputs change, much less magically updating variables to which the expression happened to have been assigned in the past. There is a word for such dynamic definitions of calculations: they are called **functions**. If you want some calculation to be dynamically redone when its inputs change, then write it as a function and call it when you need to recalculate, and if you want to (re-)assign the result of the invocation (the `return` value) to a variable, then do so.

> Is there a way to contain a reference to a variable within another variable, and not the value of the variable when the assignment was evaluated?

Again, you're confusing variables and expressions and possibly functions. A variable is merely a box, referring to some value. It maintains no record of when or how it was assigned to, or what expression was used to calculate the value being assigned to it, nor does it have any means of automatically updating itself. Being a box, a variable cannot "contain a reference to another variable".

> the best way to avoid this situation.

This is not a "situation" to be "avoided". It is the basic behavior of JavaScript.

Comment: Although I find the language a bit harsh -it almost makes me feel ashamed of not knowing and/or asking- I will accept this answer as it is nevertheless, probably, the clearest.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as others pointed out, this is expected behaviour; to do what you want, you could use a function:

```
var dynamic = "something";
var thistext = () => "text " + dynamic;
dynamic = "something different";
console.log(thistext());
```

Mind the diferences! Now thistext is a function, you must call it with `()`, and it gets evaluated every time.

Answer (score 0):

`thistext` does not "contain" the variable `dynamic`, it contains the *contents* of that variable as it was *at the time the expression was evaluated*.

Comment: Is there a way to contain a reference to a variable within another variable, andd not the value of the variable when the assignment was evaluated? Sort of like the difference between "function" and "function()" on callbacks.

Comment: @JaumeMal not for "plain data types" such as strings

Comment: @jaumemal it's better to add this comment into your main question too.

Comment: Ok, what are the rules that govern this behaviour? How is this called in javascript? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there are any general rules regarding your initial question. It's how the "+" operator is implemented - for example, you can take a look at the [ECMAScript 2016 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and see how both left and right operands are evaluated before addition/concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

When browser will compile your javascript it will look something like

```
var dynamic = undefined;
 var thisText = undefined;

dynamic = "something";

thistext = "text " + dynamic;

dynamic = "something different";

console.log(thistext);
```

when you are logging the value, you are just logging the value of thisText, which is populated when the value of dynamic is "something".

If you do the same operation after changing dynamic value you will see your desired result.

Hope this helps.